# wrapping form tag around php include files and posting form data to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have the following setup on my page pqq.php

```
     <div class="click_save">

        <form name="supplier_evaluation" id="supplier_evaluation" action="include/save_pqq.php" method="post">

        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Click Here"> 
        to save this form and come back later.

</div>

    <?php include 'general_form.php'; ?>



         <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
             //alert('Document is ready');
             $('.option_select').click(function() {
             $('#pqq_continue').load('dependables/pqq_continue.php').fadeIn("fast");
             }); //END dropdown change event
             }); //END document.ready
            </script>


            <div id="pqq_continue"></div>


    </form>
```

my general_form.php file includes the following html:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" autocomplete="off"><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" autocomplete="off"><br/>
```

my pqq_continue.php file is setup like so:

```
  <input type="radio" id="select" name="select1" value="1">

    <input type="radio" id="select2" name="select1" value="2">
```

When a user scrolls down my form I display a drop down notification giving the user the ability to save the changes to the form. This will then post to my save_pqq.php page where I insert the form values into my MySQL table.

save_pqq.php:

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    include("config.php");

    $s1=$_POST['select1'];


// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO pqq_data (bankrupt)VALUES('$s1')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result) {

   echo $s1;

}else{

 echo 'no result';   
}

    ?>
```

For some reason I am having problems getting any of my form values and getting an undefined index when i try to post the value of my radio button 'select1' in pqq_continue.php

I am guessing this is because I am wrapping my form tag around php include files? Is this not doable? Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: it is because of you are hitting the submit button which is in going to end the content of form and in that form you are not having any content.